# Обработчик нажатия кнопок

Tags: python, pyqt5, button

Есть несколько кнопок

```
    def add_functions(self):
        #Первая акция
        self.pr_buy1_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number('pr_buy1_1'))
        self.pr_buy10_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number('pr_buy10_1'))
        self.pr_buy100_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number('pr_buy100_1'))
        self.pr_buyAll_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number('pr_buyAll_1'))
        self.pr_sell1_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number('pr_sell1_1'))
        self.pr_sell10_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number('pr_sell10_1'))
        self.pr_sell100_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number('pr_sell100_1'))
        self.pr_sellAll_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number('pr_sellAll_1'))
```

Есть функция write_number, которая выполняет действия при определенном параметре, который мы передали через lambda

```
    def write_number(self, name):
       if name == 'pr_buy1_1':
           print(name)
       elif name == 'pr_buy10_1':
           print(name)
       elif name == 'pr_buy100_1':
           print(name)
       elif name == 'pr_buyAll_1':
           print(name)
```

Как это все можно сократить? И если можно, то с подробными объяснениями, пожалуйста

Comment: Я бы делал через sender, чтобы узнать отправителя сигнала.

Comment: maksik172,  пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] вашего кода и объясните, что вы хотите сделать в вашем приложении.